# which version of python packages require

Tags: python, macos, version, macports, vtk

I have numerous versions of python installed, a system python with my mac osx (10.8), and numerous version from macports.  On occation I have run into errors with different packages requiring different versions of python to run, and previously I could solve my problems by running a certain version explicitly (e.g. `python2.6 <script>`) or by changing my default python using `port select python <python-version>`.

I just struggled tremendously through installing the VTK (visualization) packages, and ***finally*** got them working by using `/usr/bin/python` instead of my standard `/opt/local/bin/python`.  These are both version 2.7 (the former is 2.7.2 and the latter 2.7.5), however.  Why can I only use one and not the other?  Is there a way to use the `/opt/` version and still have the vtk package work?

Examples of errors using the wrong python interpreter:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

and,

```
Fatal Python error: Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?) 
Abort trap
```

Comment: ... 2 years later ... I'm running into this problem now. I found this issue particularly enlightening: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/25118 . In the end, I managed to install VTK by using the homebrew-science tap: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/25118#issuecomment-42798813